# I want to modify my own my_dicts.py module from main_program.py

Tags: python, dictionary, module

I am in a situation where I need to constantly add new dictionaries to my code. So, in order to not have it all cloggued up in one single .py file, I have decided to create the module my_dicts.py, write them all there, and then import it in main_program.py.

my_dicts.py looks something like this:

```
dict1 = ...
dict2 = ...
dict3 = ...
.
.
.
```

main_program.py looks something like this:

```
import my_dicts as d

# loading some data.
.
.
.

# running some functions.
.
.
.

# creating a new dictionary with the purpose of adding it to my_dicts.py
new_dictionary = function_to_create_my_new_dictionary(some_data)
```

My question is: How do I add new_dictionary to my_dicts.py without stopping main_program.py.

Comment: this seems like a design problem to be honest. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: main_program.py reads code in another programming language, it encounters new dictionaries once in a while. I need those dictionaries stored somewhere. I am a begginner, maybe there is a better way of storing those dictionaries. All kind of suggestions are welcome. Thank you

Comment: store them in a file, as `JSON` then it makes it work regardless of language

Comment: That's good advice, thx